# Which tabs widget plugin for wordpress is better?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, widgets, sidebar

I see there are a lot of plugins to create tabbed widget in side-bar:

1. [Fun with tabs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fun-with-sidebar-tabs/)
2. [Post 2 tabs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-2-tabs-jquery-tabs/)
3. [Hybrid Tabs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hybrid-tabs/)
4. [Wordpress Tabs Slides](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-tabs-slides/)
5. [AmR Tab Menu Navigation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/horizontal-tab-menu-widget/)
6. [Tabbed Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tabbed-widgets/)

Which one is the best in configuration, speed and code-optimized? 
If any other plugin, please let me know.

Comment: you should go back and accept / comment on answers to some of your previous questions.

Comment: Can you provide some feedback to the existing answers?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Hybrid Tabs (mostly dealing with Hybrid theme):

- it is light and robust
- clean code and inline documentation
- easy to create custom tabs by code (via callback function)
- not so easy if you want to customize tabs in admin (I had coded special sidebar for myself that exposes widgets in it as available tabs)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a plugin but I have been using [jQuery Tools (Javascript Library)](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) for pretty much everything, it has become a part of WordPress for most of my projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [tabbed widgets](http://wp.digitalnature.eu/atomtest/files/2010/06/11.jpg) from my [Atom](http://digitalnature.ro/projects/atom-test/) framework. I hope this is not considered advertising :)

It's currently integrated in the theme, but you could easily extract the code that handles tabs. The difference between this and the ones you listed there is the flexibility. You can create tabs from any widget...